# Fixed top content with scrollable list view ionic

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework

Here is my code

```
<ion-view title="'Ask'">

  <ion-content has-header="true" >

    <!-- Top Content -->
    <div class="item item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" align="center" ng-model="newmsg" placeholder="Title">
  </label>
  <button class="button button-small  button-button-outline button-balanced"
          ng-click="insert(newmsg)">Add</button>


</div>

  <div class="item item-input-inset">
  <ti-segmented-control on-select="tapChanged($index)"style="width: 100%;">
    <ti-segmented-control-button class="button-balanced" title="'title 1'" selected> </ti-segmented-control-button>
    <ti-segmented-control-button class="button-balanced" title="'title 2'"></ti-segmented-control-button>
  </ti-segmented-control>
</div>    

 <!-- list view -->

  <ion-list>
   <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
   {{item.name}}!
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

above scroll entire page.

then i tried, `scroll="false"` in ion-content tag and `<ion-scroll direction="y"></ion-scroll>` in ion-list but the scroll view not scroll to bottom of the list items.

Any one have a idea to solve this ?.

thanks in advance.

**Edit**

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3nHIYqOSwczWMeqURMR?p=preview) (thanks LeftyX for runnable code)

Comment: You might have some errors with your scripts. You cannot comment HTML with // You have to use <!-- comment --> instead. This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3nHIYqOSwczWMeqURMR?p=preview) might help you to spot your problem.

Comment: i know, i just mention here..now code updated.You have any idea for fixed top content with scrollable list at buttom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option if you want to have headers and sub-headers with a different heights - as in your situation - is to use `sass` and customize the variables.

From the directory of your app you can run:

```
ionic setup sass
```

and ionic would create the scss files and the gulp task associated.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L166) the height of the subheader

```
$bar-subheader-height: $bar-height !default;
```

is equal to the height of the header: 44px:

```
$bar-height: 44px !default;
```

You could change the value for `$bar-subheader-height` adding a line in the `ionic.app.scss` file (folder scss):

```
$bar-subheader-height: 150px;
```

and the gulp task would compile into the modified `css` file.

The other option is to redefine the css rules. As you can see in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T9tI5HvEI9TYj44ydU9D?p=preview)

I have headers and sub-headers (using the same directives `ion-header-bar`):

```
  <ion-view>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" align="center" ng-model="newmsg" placeholder="Title">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-small  button-button-outline button-balanced" ng-click="insert(newmsg)">Add</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <ti-segmented-control on-select="tapChanged($index)" style="width: 100%;">
          <ti-segmented-control-button class="button-balanced" title="'title 1'" selected> </ti-segmented-control-button>
          <ti-segmented-control-button class="button-balanced" title="'title 2'"></ti-segmented-control-button>
        </ti-segmented-control>
      </div>

    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content class="has-subheader">

      <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

  </ion-view>
```

in the css I have created 2 styles which are going to be applied to the second `<ion-header-bar>` and the `<ion-content>`:

```
.bar-subheader
{
  height: 114px !important;
  border: none;

}

.has-subheader {
    top: 160px !important;
}
```

As you can see it works as expected but you might run in some odd behaviour. I would suggest to go for the sass variables.

UPDATE:

If you only want to change the behaviour in one page you can customize the `bar-subheader` element:

```
.bar-subheader.custom
{
  height: 114px !important;
  border: none;
}
```

and define a custom `has-subheader`:

```
.has-subheader-custom {
    top: 160px !important;
}
```

Which you're going to reference here:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader custom">
```

and here:

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader-custom">
```

and this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2yYRWsWXQXDgfrjZ6sB8?p=preview) should guide you.

Comment: I need to change only for particular page But it will change all page sub-header height.

Comment: You're very welcome chimbu. Don't forget to accept the answer if you're happy with it. Upvotes are very welcome :-). Cheers.